# How to get Doxygen to ignore indentation but still create ref links?

Tags: c, doxygen

C code. Doxygen 1.8.3.

Some files start with large documentation blocks. Most users will read those multi-paragraph comments directly from the code files. Thus, indentation is important for clarity.

But that indentation causes Doxygen to treat the text as 'code' (creating a boxed output in the wrong typeface), and to ignore keywords.

Using \verbatim disables keywords.

Is there a way to force Doxygen to respect the indentation *and* create ref links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boxed text is created using Markdown.

Markdown treats text indented by either 4 spaces or a tab as a code block delimiter (http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode).

You can either set

MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = NO

in your configuration file, or use a smaller indentation level to suppress box generation.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the tab size to 5 did the trick.
Is there a way to disable Markdown per specific files?
I didn't find any such option in the manual.

Comment: I only know of the global MARKDOWN_SUPPORT flag.